# Android - Gesture Detection (Swipe up/down) on particular view

Tags: android, swipe, gesture-recognition, onfling

I am trying to implement the OnGestureListener in Android. 
I have three TextViews in my layout. 
What  i am trying to achieve is to set Gesture Listener for two of the textViews .
Here is the **layout** -

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOne"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="One" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTwo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvOne"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Two" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvThree"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTwo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Three" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the **activity**

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
    import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;

    public class TimeActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {

    GestureDetector gestureScanner;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wheelview);
        gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Test", "On Fling");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

At present Fling for all the three textviews is getting called .
 Is there any way through which i can set the **Gesture Listener for some particular views in the layout**.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Do this in your `onCreate` method.

```
findViewById(R.id.tvOne).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { 
            @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(event);
           }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer.  Both of the answers are correct. I can not accept both the answers , I am up voting you both.

Comment: How to set onLongPress for particular layout(Relative).

Comment: @reegan29, the same way. One of the override methods on a GestureDetector is `onLongPress()`

Comment: How can we know which view was flung?

Comment: @SrujanBarai In above case `View` with id `R.id.tvOne` has listener so thats the one being touched. Or you can use the `View` passed in `onTouch()`

Comment: Oh yhh that is obvious but the `onFling` method does not have a `view` parameter.

Comment: How can i use ACTION_MOVE using this gestureScanner

Answer (score 11):

You can set `OnTouchListener`s to individual `TextView`s.

```
findViewById(R.id.tvOne).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
         // Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### A suggestion

If you don't want to detect all gesture,try this class:
[SimpleGestureListener](https://gist.github.com/CoXier/066da346bdf19c519457300f7c7988f6/revisions) created by myself.

Now here are some snippets for this class's usage.

### Usage

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private GestureDetector mDetector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SimpleGestureListener simpleGestureListener = new SimpleGestureListener();
        simpleGestureListener.setListener(new SimpleGestureListener.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollHorizontal(float dx) {
                Log.i(TAG,"horizontal = " +dx);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollVertical(float dy) {
                Log.i(TAG,"vertical = " +dy);
            }
        });
        mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, simpleGestureListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

It can be used for detecting swiping gesture :

- left or right
- up or down

Comment: Please make you interface "Listener" public in your github project , Thanks