# Register TouchListener on a particaular view using GestureDetectorCompat

Tags: android, view, gesture, ontouchlistener

I have two `TextView` and I want to set on `setOnTouchListener` only for a `TextView`.
I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931510/android-gesture-detection-swipe-up-down-on-particular-view) and did that as stated in this answer but I could not solve the problem. I am using `GestureDetectorCompat`. I have tried many solution but still the same problem.

When I am touching the `textview1` the `onFling` method is getting called from register `onTouch` listener but when I am touching `textview2` the `onFling` method is still getting called from its `life cycle method`. I am not getting why its calling `onFling` on un-register textview. 
Please help me.

**acticity_main.xml**

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#ffcc99"
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#ffcc88"
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    private static String DEBUG_TAG = "debug";
    private TextView mTextView;
    private GestureDetectorCompat mGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        findViewById(R.id.textview1).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
                Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "setOnTouchListener");
                mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "onTouchEvent");
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "onDown");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "onShowPress");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapUp");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "onScroll");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress");
    }
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling " + e1.getX() + " - " + e2.getX());
}
}
```

Comment: this is because you are calling `mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);` inside `Activity#onTouchEvent()`

Comment: So where should I put it?

Comment: in `OnTouchListener#onTouch`, as you are already doing

Comment: after removing mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); from Activity's onTouchEvent this is calling onFling only on register view. But still Activity's onTouch getting called. Is it OK?

Comment: there is no such method: `Activity#onTouch`

Comment: I mean onTouchEvent...sorry.

Comment: from the docs: `Called when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views under it. This is most useful to process touch events that happen outside of your window bounds, where there is no view to receive it.`

Comment: Btw..  you solved the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the `onTouchEvent` method outside the `onCreate` and then it will only work for `textview1`. Because you have applied `onTouchEvent` outside the `onCreate` it will be called whenever there is gesture event on the whole `MainActivity` since the `onTouchEvent` outside the `onCreate` also is calling `mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)`

The statement

```
 mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
```

automatically calls the onTouchEvent of the `GestureDetectorCompact` Calls which indeed makes the appropriate call backs provided by `OnGestureListener` based on the motion event.