# Android onScrolled not called when View is set to GONE

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scroll

I am trying to hide a RelativeLayout when I scroll up and show it when I scroll down. onScroll works fine and is invoked every time until View is set to GONE.

```
final RelativeLayout placeHeaderMain = findViewById(R.id.place_header_main);

mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (dy > 0) {
            // Scrolling up
            placeHeaderMain.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {
            // Scrolling down
           placeHeaderMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

I want my listener to continue working after setting the View to Gone in order to make it Visible when scrolled down.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are there enough items to be scrolled?

That code above won't be triggered if `dy == 0`. It could be not enough items to make the scroll and it will return `dy` **equal** to `0`, father more it won't to call `onScroll(...)`

What `dy` do you have when `RelativeLayout` has hidden?
Try to check that method below:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is that I don't have enough items to scroll through. I guess I have to hide the header layout only after I have enough items to scroll through after the View is Gone.

Comment: Yep, happy codding :)

Comment: You may mark my answer with an arrow (accept), to notify people that suggested answer is solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the view to **INVISIBLE** and not to **GONE**.
 when you set any view to `View.GONE` he is invisible and it doesn't take any space inside your layout ,  but when you set a view to `View.INVISIBLE` like before he will be invisible but unlike  `View.GONE` your view still takes up space inside the layout.

Comment: Yes, I don't want the layout to take space. I want to hide it. The problem was that I don't have enough items to make the scroll.

Comment: You can try to look at  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931510/android-gesture-detection-swipe-up-down-on-particular-view) to detect when your user swiped up/down